# python - how to input results of the arima test to a data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, arima

I'm new to the python and is stuck at coding the procedure of inputting results of the ARIMA test to a data frame. So, I got the ARIMA results by coding the following :

```
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df_month.Weighted_Price_box,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))

            data = {'parameters' : [param], 'aic' : [results.aic]}
        except:

            continue

rt=pd.DataFrame(data)
rt
```

The output is :

```
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:407.22578000041864
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:238.18574141909036
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:294.4619377438503
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:293.02415782731146
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:247.3954939335222
ARIMA(0, 0, 0)x(1, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:240.81509476560723
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:424.3477569952406
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:322.92052137636273
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:230.11538217516411
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(0, 1, 1, 12)12 - AIC:168.44268972392362
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 0, 12)12 - AIC:221.44384124449488
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 0, 1, 12)12 - AIC:201.34872206655223
ARIMA(0, 0, 1)x(1, 1, 0, 12)12 - AIC:189.5734656288126
......
        aic parameters
0  57.95076  (1, 1, 1)
```

As you can see, my dataframe called rt contains only one line instead of 13.

Comment: You're redefining `data` on every loop of `for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:`. Although I can't be sure that this is the issue, I would imagine that you need to define a list before the `for` loop

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't be sorry, there is a difference between a bad question and a simple question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a list to append the content and the use it to create the DF.

**Ex:**

```
data = []
for param in pdq:
    for param_seasonal in seasonal_pdq:
        try:
            mod = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(df_month.Weighted_Price_box,
                                            order=param,
                                            seasonal_order=param_seasonal,
                                            enforce_stationarity=False,
                                            enforce_invertibility=False)

            results = mod.fit()

            print('ARIMA{}x{}12 - AIC:{}'.format(param, param_seasonal, results.aic))

            data.append({'parameters' : [param], 'aic' : [results.aic]})
        except:

            continue

rt=pd.DataFrame(data)
rt
```

Comment: Thank you guys for the prompt and explicit explanation!